# Get Device Model in windows Phone 8.1 Runtime

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

is there a way to retrieve friendly device model in  windows phone 8.1?

`EasClientDeviceInformation a = new EasClientDeviceInformation();
 String b = a.SystemProductName; // RM-994 not lumia 1320`

this Api doesn't return device friendly name.

Comment: As far as the documentation goes, you cannot get the device details such as **lumia 1320** from `EasClientDeviceInformation`. The property `FriendlyName` is the name that the user gave the device, such as `Soheil Ghahremani's Windows Phone`.

Comment: is there a mapping list of SystemProductName and DeviceModel? @Barnstokkr

Comment: The best thing you can probably use is the `SystemSku`, however it does not return *Nokia Lumia 1320* it will return something like *NOKIA RM-994_country_some_number*, then if you go and look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_Lumia_1320 you can see that RM-994 is the international version of the Lumia 1320.

Comment: is there a list for all windows phone model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to get a friendly name like Lumia 1320 directly from the API, you need to use https://github.com/ailon/PhoneNameResolver to convert the name from API (RM-994) to the friendly name.

Comment: what about upcoming devices? Looks like library maps models with name.
SystemProductName should suffice.

Comment: If there is a new device (not very likely according to the current development), the library author will add it

Comment: yes..but in this case we need to rebuild code. Worried about things after deployment.